# How to let JQuery affect divs inside an ui-view?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, animation, uiview, angular-ui-router

I am trying to add animations to divs inside an ui-view. But it looks like the jquery is not affecting my divs. When i add the divs outside the ui-view directily into index.html it is working though. But when the divs are in an html document inside an ui-view it won't work. The ui-router is working perfectly fine though, although I probably missed something in that too because the code below is minimalized.

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="animations.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="animateApp">
   <a ui-sref="slideshowdocument"></a>
   <div ui-view></div>
</body>
<html>
```

slideshowdocument.html

```
<div id="animatethis">
<!-- slideshow stuff -->
</div>
```

app.js

```
var animateApp = angular.module('animateApp', [
'ui.router',
'ngAnimate'
]);

animateApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
     $stateProvider 

.state('slideshowdocument', {
        url: '/slideshow',
        templateUrl: 'pages/slideshowdocument.html'
    });
```

animations.js

```
//animations here
```

I even tried this so animations.js is loading in the same time as the ui-view.

index.html

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
 <div ui-view="animationshere">

 </head>
 <body ng-app="animateApp">
   <a ui-sref="slideshowdocument"></a>
   <div ui-view="documenthere"></div>
 </body>
 <html>
```

script.html

```
  <script src="animations.js"></script>
```

app.js

```
    .state('slideshowdocument', {
    url: '/slideshow',
    views: {
        'animationshere': { templateUrl: 'pages/slideshowdocument.html'},
       'documenthere': { templateUrl: 'pages/script.html'}

     }
    });
```

Comment: try adding jquery above angular.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution kinda.

I tried adding

```
 <script src="animations.js"></script>
```

to the slideshowdocument.html

Did not work when i added it before by html code. Did work when i added after the html code. It is probably because the divs don't exist yet when the code is executed. Not the best solution because i have to load animations.js for every state of the ui-view i want to use it for.